# in_array function always returns false

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and when using in_array to check if object exists it always returns false.

As an example, here is the array:

```
array:1 [
0 => "name1, name2, name3"
]
```

and this is how I check if index exists

```
if(!in_array('name1', $array)) { return FALSE; } else { return TRUE;}
```

Name1 exists in array I have however I think I'm missing something small here.

Not sure what it could be or even if this function is the right function to use to check? Expected result is to be true as object exists.

Thanks

Comment: And it should return false. Your array is one long string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your array only has one item with a long string in_array returns false since there is no exact match.
What you can do is to use preg_grep which is regex for arrays.

```
var_dump(preg_grep("/name1/i", $arr));
```

https://3v4l.org/dmvsR

You can use it with bool return like this:

```
if(preg_grep("/name1/i", $arr)){
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

Since preg_grep returns empty if nothing is found.
And empty array means false in an if().

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your array is one element that is one string, it does not contain multiple elements. If you want to use `in_array()`, it must be an array - not a string.

There's a few different ways of achieving this, one us by using `explode()` on the element to make it into an array and then use `in_array()`.

You can also return the value of `in_array()` instead of running a check yourself - the returnvalue of the function is a boolean `true`/`false`.

```
$array = array("name1, name2, name3");
$parts = explode(", ", $array[0]);
return in_array("name1", $parts);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/G0QEN

Comment: This assumes the search value is always in array item [0].

Comment: Aye, that it does. The array presented in the question was of that structure - if the results can vary, one would need to know which element to run this on.

Comment: Thanks, as Andrea mentioned I'm using first item to validate so it should be fine however while trying this solution I get this error "The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given."